# jquery - targetting a select using $this

Tags: jquery, target

I am trying to get individual selects (which have the same class as other selects) to respond to a .change function, however it only works on one of the selects. If you test out this code it will make more sense. Try to add a few "ON/OFF events", and then select "Specified Time" in the various selects. You'll see only the first one responds. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Please see the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var neweventstring = '<div class="event">Turns <select name="ONOFF"><option value="On">ON</option><option value="Off">OFF</option></select> at: <select name="setto" class="setto"><option>Select Time</option><option value="Sunrise">Sunrise</option><option value="Sunset">Sunset</option><option value="specifiedtime">Specified Time</option></select></div>';

   $('#addmondaysevent').click(function () {
      $('#monday .events').append(neweventstring);
   });

   $('.setto').change(function() {  
      alert('The function is called');
      if($("option:selected", this).val() =="specifiedtime"){
          alert('If returns true');
          $(this).css("background-color", "#cc0000");
          $(this).after('<div class="specifictime"><input type="text" value="00" style="width:30px"/> : <input type="text" value="00"  style="width:30px"> <select name="ampm"><option value="AM" selected>AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select></div>')
          }
   });
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="monday">
    <h2>Mondays</h2>

     <div class="events">
     <div class="event">
            Turn 
            <select name="ONOFF">
            <option value="On">ON</option>
            <option value="Off">OFF</option>
            </select>
            at: 
            <select name="setto" class="setto">
            <option>Select Time</option>
            <option value="Sunrise">Sunrise</option>
            <option value="Sunset">Sunset</option>
            <option value="specifiedtime">Specified Time</option>
            </select>
       </div>
      [<a id="addmondaysevent">Add an ON/OFF event</a>] 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you chose Andbdrew's solution please consider marking his solution as answered :-)

Comment: The points, while pointless (har), are a fun part of the site. Plus, the higher the rep, the more chicks we get.

Answer (score 4):

the change event handler is only getting added once (on document ready). You should use $.delegate or $.on to attach events to elements that get added to page later. for example, something like the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var neweventstring = '<div class="event">Turns <select name="ONOFF"><option value="On">ON</option><option value="Off">OFF</option></select> at: <select name="setto" class="setto"><option>Select Time</option><option value="Sunrise">Sunrise</option><option value="Sunset">Sunset</option><option value="specifiedtime">Specified Time</option></select></div>';

$('#addmondaysevent').click(function () {
    $('#monday .events').append(neweventstring);
});

$('#monday .events').on("change", ".setto", function() {  
    alert('The function is called');
    if($("option:selected", this).val() =="specifiedtime"){
        alert('If returns true');
        $(this).css("background-color", "#cc0000");
        $(this).after('<div class="specifictime"><input type="text" value="00" style="width:30px"/> : <input type="text" value="00"  style="width:30px"> <select name="ampm"><option value="AM" selected>AM</option><option value="PM">PM</option></select></div>')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. Does the above code work for you? Did you test it? I'm on FF. Thanks

Comment: +1 for the .on suggestion it's a very good method ... good riddance to ".live" :-)

Comment: Be sure to upvote helpful answers and accept the best one, @Maureen.

Answer (score 1):

You're only applying it to one. Only one select has the `setto` class applied to it, which is what you're binding is doing.

```
$(document).on('theEvent','theSelector', function () {
    DoKungfu();
});
```

is your friend. This will bind the event to any item in the DOM currently matching the selector and any item added later that matches it.

Comment: Initially there is only one, but I'm using a .append to add more.

Comment: yes, but when you bind the change event, there is only one .setto present. Yatrix is correct, just not very verbose. :)

Comment: Ahh.. ok I'm starting to understand now. Thanks Yatrix and Andbdrew.

Comment: I'm curious why I was downvoted as well. I wasn't aware the SO community punishes people for the right answer now. I'll have to keep that in mind.

Comment: For the record, if you call doKungFu, your browser will kick you in the face.

Answer (score 1):

Like Yatrix said, your first **select** is missing **class="setto"**. With that in mind, you will also have to bind the change event as such.

```
$('#monday .event').on('change', '.setto', function() {
```

Comment: This did the trick. I used Andbdrew's code above and just changed .delegate to .on like you've suggested here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of this,"option:selected" ...

```
if($(this,"option:selected").val() == "specifiedtime") {

 ... do stuff ...
```

**UPDATE** @Yatrixs suggestion solved the persistence error.

Answer (score -1):

try bind event again after you append:

```
$('#monday .events').append(neweventstring);
```

Comment: it is not an answer, it is comment